# Intermediate problems between $CC^0$ and $ACC^0$

Tags: reference-request, circuit-complexity

#### Definitions

$CC^0[m]$ is the set of languages decidable by constant-depth polynomial-size circuits consisting only of unbounded-fanin $MOD_m$ gates. We write $CC^0$ to mean the union over all $m$. $ACC^0$ is identical but we also allow unbounded fanin $AND$, $OR$, and $NOT$ gates. I'll assume nonuniform circuits here because I think it makes the question the most interesting.

We'll call a language $L$ "$ACC^0$-intermediate" if $L \in ACC^0$ and it is neither known that $L \in CC^0$ nor that $L \in CC^0 \implies CC^0 = ACC^0$.

#### Question

Are there any known $ACC^0$-intermediate problems? Especially "interesting" or "natural" ones?

#### Motivation

$CC^0$ is by some metrics one of the smallest classes where meaningfully lower-bounding its power has proved incredibly hard. But compare this to, say, $TC^0$, where we at least have plenty of non-trivial constructions (multiplication, division, and sorting all come to mind). Whereas the only interesting constructions I know of for $CC^0$ are randomized circuits for $AND$ and slightly-better-than-naive circuits for $MAJ$. Maybe if we could identify $ACC^0$-intermediate problems, they could serve as targets for $CC^0$ constructions that are both easier to make and don't have (debatably) unrealistic implications.

#### Partial ideas

One trivial answer would be $AND$ with the fanin reduced. I believe it is also possible that $MOD_r \in CC^0[m]$ with $(r,m) = 1$, but that the constants involved are galactic in terms of $r$. This would only collapse the various $CC^0[m]$ classes together, which technically satisfies the question but misses the point.